# Select distinct without creating IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select a distinct set of elements from a collection using Linq *without* creating an IEqualityComparer class.  I can't figure out how to create a lambda expression that is evaluated as an IEqualityComparer to use with `Distinct()`.  So I used grouping to, for example, select customers with distinct names:

```
var distinctCustomers = new List<Customer>();
var groups= customers.GroupBy (cust => cust.Name);
foreach (var g in groups)
{
  foreach (var customer in g)
  {
    distinctCustomers.Add (customer);
    break;
  }
}
```

But this seems icky.

I'd either like to use `Distinct` with a lambda expression

```
var distinctCustomers = customers.Distinct ( <lambda here ?> )
```

or a cleaner Linq expression than listed above.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean you want to Distinct by certain value

Comment: You're looking for DistinctBy - not included in the BCL but various implementations are readily available

Comment: I would recommend implementing MoreLinq dll since it already has build in distinct by function http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to reimplement a `DistinctBy` (or use one like [the one in MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs)), you can do this via `GroupBy` and a `Select` in which you just select the first element within each group:

```
var distinctCustomers = customers.GroupBy(cust => cust.Name).Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll look into using  an extended Linq library too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) from Jon Skeet, which has a DistinctBy method. Or take it's implementation to your code.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> distinctCustomers = customers.DistinctBy(c => c.Name);
```